# JavaScript: лишняя итерация цикла do while

Tags: javascript

Этот код, взятый с [javascript.ru](http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/45190-najjti-vse-vkhozhdeniya-podstroki-s-pomoshhyu-indexof-v-cikle.html), ищет все вхождения подстроки "иа":

```
var str="Ослик иа-иа посмотрел на виадук";
var poisk="иа";
var i=0;
do {
    var x = str.indexOf(poisk,i);
    i=x+1;
    alert(x)
} while (x!=-1)
```

Недостаток этого кода в том, что он проходит одну лишнюю итерацию, когда `indexOf` уже вернул `-1`. Я модифицировал этот код следующим образом:

```
var string = "JavaScript и Java - разные языки!";
var substring = "Java";

var nextDesiredSubstringPosition = 0;

while (desiredSubstringPosition!=-1){ // позиция подстроки, которую мы ищмем
    var desiredSubstringPosition = string.indexOf(substring, nextDesiredSubstringPosition);
    if (desiredSubstringPosition === -1 ){break;}
    nextDesiredSubstringPosition = desiredSubstringPosition + 1;// в следующей итерации начинаем отсюда
}
```

Лишнюю итерацию я убрал, но получается что условие при `while` никогда не выполняется в строке с этим условием, а выход из цикла осуществляется засчет вложенного `if`. Программа работает, но код не логичный. Можно ли убрать эту нелогичность, не усложняя код?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Почему бы вам не сделать так?

```js
var str = "Ослик иа-иа посмотрел на виадук";
var poisk = "иа";
var x, i = 0;

while ((x = str.indexOf(poisk,i)) != -1) {
    alert(x)
    i=x+1;
}
```

Внутри условия цикла вычисляем x и тут же его сравниваем.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема с циклами while, в отсутствии блока инициализации. Из-за этого решение для них, либо как в соседнем ответе выносить присваивание в проверку, либо как в вопросе добавлять `if` внутрь цикла.

Либо можно просто эмулировать блок инициализации.

Пример для цикла с постусловием:

```js
var str = "Ослик иа-иа посмотрел на виадук";
var poisk = "иа";
var i = 0;
var x = str.indexOf(poisk, i);
if (x != -1) {
  do {
    console.log(x)
    i = x + 1;
    x = str.indexOf(poisk, i);
  } while (x != -1)
}
```

Пример для цикла с предусловием

```js
var str = "Ослик иа-иа посмотрел на виадук";
var poisk = "иа";
var i = 0;

var x = str.indexOf(poisk, i);
while (x != -1) {
  console.log(x)
  i = x + 1;
  x = str.indexOf(poisk, i);
}
```

Либо просто воспользоваться циклом `for`

```js
var str = "Ослик иа-иа посмотрел на виадук";
var poisk = "иа";

for (var x = str.indexOf(poisk, 0); x != -1; x = str.indexOf(poisk, x + 1)) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Цикл `while` не без причины имеет одно выражение, которое интерпретируется как логическое, он в отличии от цикла `for` предназначен по большей части для итераторов -

```
while( iterator.hasNext() ) { ... }
```

Так же наилучшим образом подходит операций с изменяемым в теле объектом -

```
while( array.length ){ array.pop(); }
```

Или -

```
while( array.length < 5 ){ array.push( {  } ) ; }
```

`do while` отличается от `while` лишь тем, что его тело гарантированно выполнится один раз. Первым что пришло в голову чтобы продемонстрировать его работу, это специфичность `js` итераторов, которые лишены метода `hasNext` -

```
let map = new Map();

let iterator = map[Symbol.iterator]();

do {
  let data = iterator.next();
}while( ! data.done )
```

Видите как он устроен? Проверку на следующий элемент можно сделать предварительно получив текущий элемент. Тоже самое ниже с использованием `while` что выглядит не так красиво, ведь в первый раз `data` инициализируется за пределами цикла, а если условие правдиво, то уже продолжает в теле цикла -

```
let map = new Map();

let iterator = map[Symbol.iterator]();
let data = iterator.next();

while( ! data.done ){
  data = iterator.next();
}
```

Можно сделать как ниже, **но этот код я показываю лишь для того, чтобы Вы раз и навсегда запомнили что так делать нельзя**! Такой **ленивый код** допустимо писать только на форумах для примера, но в серьёзных проектах за такое ругают и уход от такого стиля обычно говорит об опыте человека.

```
let map = new Map();

let iterator = map[Symbol.iterator]();
let data = null;

while( ! ( data = iterator.next() ).done ){ ... }
```

И самое главное что нужно сказать о `do while` новичку, это то что он в реальных проектах вообще не используется! Ни одного раза не видел в крутых проектах этот цикл, потому-что правила написания кода диктует поведение, для которого этот цикл просто не нужен. Поэтому не заморачивайтесь на нем и не ищите способы его применения.